# PHP テキストファイルの編集機能を実装したい。

Tags: php

## やっていること

テキストファイルに入力した内容を編集したい。

### 詳細な要件

同様に、指定された番号のものだけ編集できるようにする
a.入力フォームとは別に、編集番号指定用フォームを用意する。項目は編集対象番号。
b.POST送信にて編集番号を送信する。その際if文で編集フォームから値が送信された場合のみの処理に分岐させておく
c.fileで配列化して読み込み、ループさせる
d.explodeを使って投稿番号を取得する
e.各投稿番号とPOSTで送信された編集番号を比較し、イコールの時の配列値を取得する
f.(1)で用意した入力フォームに、取得した配列値を入力済み状態で表示させる
g.その値をPOSTで送信して編集を行うが、編集かどうかわかるようにタグを用いて、編集モードかどうかを判別する
h.編集内容の値が送信されたら、同じくc～dの処理を行い、eと同じように番号の比較を行って、イコールの時に配列値を取得するのではなく送信された値と差し替える
i.差し替えた配列をテキストに上書き保存する

### つまっているところ

現在つまっているのが上記のf.になります。
まずfの、下記のコードで２つ以上のコメントを投稿した状態で、編集用のフォームに数値を入力して編集ボタンを押すと投稿フォームにその数値に対応する値を表示するところまでやりたいです。現状それをやると、対応する値ではなくかならずidの最後の値がフォームに表示されてしまいます。これを直して編集フォームに入力した数値を押すと、投稿フォーム（名前と、コメント）にその数値に対応する値を表示させたいです。

## 全コード

```
<?php
// グローバル変数
$file = "kadai_5.txt";
$comment = $_POST["comment"];
$name = $_POST["name"];

// 投稿機能
if (!empty($comment && $name)) {
 $date = date("Y/m/d H:i:s");
 $fp_all = fopen($file, "a");
 $data = file_get_contents($file);
 $file_data = explode("\n", $data);
 $count = count($file_data);
 fwrite($fp_all, $count++ . "<>" . $name . "<>" . $comment . "<>" . $date . "<>" . PHP_EOL);
 fclose($fp_all);
}

// ファイルの中身を配列化
$file_arr = file($file);
// echo '<pre>';
// var_dump($file_arr);
// echo '<pre>';


//削除機能
if (!empty($_POST["deleteId"])) {
 $delete = $_POST["deleteId"];
 $fp_write = fopen($file, "w");
 foreach ($file_arr as $file_txt) {
  $file_split = explode("<>", $file_txt);
  $id = $file_split[0];
  $name = $file_split[1];
  $comment = $file_split[2];
  $date = $file_split[3];
  if ($id == $delete) {
   // echo '<p>';
   echo "削除されました";
   // echo '<p>';
  } else {
   if ($id > $delete) {
    $id = $id - 1;
   }
   fwrite($fp_write, $id . "<>" . $name . "<>" . $comment . "<>" . $date . "<>" . PHP_EOL);
  }
 }
 fclose($fp_write);
}
// if (!empty($_POST['updateId'])) {
//  $update = $_POST['updateId'];
//  echo $update;
// }
// 編集機能
if (!empty($_POST['updateId'])) {
 $update = $_POST['updateId'];
 // aにすると権限が消えない。
 $fp_write = fopen($file, "w");
 // echo $update;
 // $writeData = ($_POST['updateId'] ?: count($file_arr) + 1) . "<>" . $_POST['name'] . "<>" . $_POST['comment'];
 // echo gettype($writeData);
 // $hidden_update = $_POST["update"];
 $submit_type2 = $_POST["hiddeneditnum"];
 if (isset($_POST["name"])) {
  $name = $_POST["name"];
 }
 if (isset($_POST["comment"])) {
  $comment = $_POST["comment"];
 }
 // $fp3 = fopen("kadai_2-6.txt", "w");
 foreach ($file_arr as $file_txt) {
  $file_split = explode("<>", $file_txt);
  $id = $file_split[0];
  $name = $file_split[1];
  $comment = $file_split[2];
  $date = $file_split[3];

  // if ($id == $submit_type2) {
  if ($id == $update) {
   $file_split[0] = $id;
   $file_split[1] = $name;
   $file_split[2] = $comment;
   $file_split[3] = $date;
  }
  fwrite($fp_write, $id . "<>" . $name . "<>" . $comment . "<>" . $date . "<>" . PHP_EOL);
 }
 fclose($fp_write);
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>

<body>
 <form action="" method="post">
  名前：<input type="text" name="name" value="<?php if (!empty($_POST["updateId"])) {
                                            echo $name;
                                           } ?>" />
  コメント：<input type="text" name="comment" value="<?php if (!empty($_POST["updateId"])) {
                                                 echo $comment;
                                                } ?>" />
  <input type="submit" value="送信" />
  <input type="hidden" name="updateId" value="<?php echo $_POST["updateId"]; ?>" />
 </form>
 <br>
 <form action="" method="post">
  削除id：<input type="number" name="deleteId" value="" />
  <button type="submit">削除</button>
 </form>

 <form action="" method="post">
  編集id：<input type="number" name="updateId" value="<?php if (!empty($_POST["updateId"])) {
                                                    echo $_POST["updateId"];
                                                   } else {
                                                    echo "";
                                                   } ?>" />
  <input type="hidden" name="update" value="<?php if (!empty($_POST["updateId"])) {
                                             echo $_POST["updateId"];
                                            } else {
                                             echo "";
                                            } ?>">
  <button type=" submit">編集</button>
 </form>
 <br>

 <?php
 foreach ($file_arr as $file_txt) {
  $file_split = explode("<>", $file_txt);
  $id = $file_split[0];
  $name = $file_split[1];
  $comment = $file_split[2];
  $date = $file_split[3];  
  print_r($id . "<>" . $name . "<>" . $comment . "<>" . $date);
  echo "<br>";
 }
 ?>
</body>

</html>
```

## 試したこと

すみません、エラー文がないので検討がつきませんでした。

## 質問者のスキルレベル

Laravelはブログやメディア系のアプリならとりあえず作れるレベル、保守性は意識しない。
ただpurePHPでの成果物作りはほぼ初心者（１週間ほど）です。

何かアドバイスあればよろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

編集機能のifブロックの中でforで$nameと$commentにずっと代入していますね。
そのため該当の$idが見つかってもfor分は止まらないため
一番最後のデータの$nameと$commentが表示されてます。
一時的な変数とビューで使う変数名は別で定義したほうが混乱せず使えると思います。

```
 foreach ($file_arr as $file_txt) {
  $file_split = explode("<>", $file_txt);
  $id = $file_split[0];
  $name = $file_split[1];    //$nameにいったん入れているがこの変数はforでぐるぐる
  $comment = $file_split[2]; //まわっているためforの最後のデータが入ってしまっている。
  $date = $file_split[3];
```

あとは今回の質問とは関係ないですが、
・PHPのエラーがないとの話ですがNoticeレベルのエラーは発生しているようです。
・編集削除投稿の処理は並列で互いに干渉しないように排他的（elseifでつなげるとか、関数化してしまうとか）に書くとよいと思います
・サニタイズされていないので<>のデータが入ってきたりするとデータが崩れます。
・XSSの脆弱性があります。

ぜひ考慮してみてください。